# Как считать таблицу из .doc файла в rust?

Tags: rust

Если с `.docx` файлами все понятно, то что делать с `.doc` мне очень не понятно.

Если коротко, в целов задача такая: есть `.docx` и `.doc` файлы с таблицами внутри, эти таблицы надо считать, (немного преобразовать данные из таблиц), переделать в `.xlsx`

Все, за исключением работы с `.doc` у меня +- вышло